# jquery : $(document).ready only accept anonymous handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have a defined function as a handler to jQuery's $(document).ready() instead of anonymous function ?

I've done several experiments but to no avail. One of them is here : http://pastebin.com/XHKPc879.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, a regular function is a function just like an anonymous one is.

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/XFRYz/).

In your example, you're actually *calling* the function and passing its return value to the document read, because you have the closing `()` on it. Leave those off, and it should work.

Of course, if you call a function that *returns* a function, [that works too](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/RMvEB/).

**EDIT**

First link:

```
function foo() {
    alert("ohai!");
}

$(document).ready(foo);
```

Second link:

```
function fooGen() {
    return function() {
        alert("kthxbai!");
    };
}

$(document).ready(fooGen());
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible:

```
function pancakes() { /* Do interesting things */ }
$(document).ready(pancakes);
```

The problem with your pastebin:

```
$(document).ready(test());
```

is the you're calling the `test` function when you say `test()`, just drop the parentheses and you're good.

Comment: Not only possible, but arguably a good way to keep your code in nice manageable chunks, and also from nesting it all the way beyond the right margin. :)

Comment: @WestonC Wait, you mean if you turn code on its side the left margin isn't a graph of how awesome it is?!

Comment: Only if you're programming using the [Whitespace](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/) language.

Comment: The Whitespace language isn't [polite enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercal) for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also name your anonymous function so it's not quite anonymous:

```
$(function bob(){
   alert('hi');
});
```

This is occasionally useful when debugging.